# Mapping mouse events in vim through putty not working

Tags: vim, dictionary, mouse, xterm

I'm using Vim 6.3.81 on a x-term through putty. I wanted to map mouse events (like wheel-button click , double click) to specific events using my .vimrc . I've looked at the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29#Mapping_mouse_events) and based on it, defined the following map in my .vimrc:

```
:nnoremap <2-LeftMouse> :set invnumber<CR>
```

However , it is not working - double-click is not toggling the line numbers as intended . Do I have to change my X settings to get vim to accept mouse events ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you issued a `:set mouse=a` or similar?

Vim can accept mouse input through the terminal, but it needs to be explicitly enabled.  Both PuTTY and xTerm support it.

`:help mouse` for more details.

Comment: Thanks...works now like a charm. But now I have a bigger problem - enabling mouse events dissable text selection via mouse, which is not what I want. You have answered a similar question of mine regarding text selection in vim through putty , so I guess you know what I wanted...

Anyway , this is the best answer possible I guess - i'll just have to decide between enabling mouse events and disabling text selection!!

Comment: Hold down shift while selecting using the mouse and PuTTY will pick up the mouse events itself, rather than handing them to the application.

Comment: Great answer to a tricky situation !! So the solution is just to hold down the shift key while selecting text using mouse , after ensuring mouse is activated in vim. Thanks !